# Hiding mysql connection datas on Git repository

Tags: git, security, github

I have a public repository on Github. It's an online web service. We just want to share source codes of our web service. We are storing all connections datas and functions on `connect.php` file. And including it to other files, when necessary. We want to hide this file from all visitors except collaborators of repository.

Is it possible? Or are there other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is stop Git from tracking the file changes.

1. Move any sensitive strings from `connect.php` into a new file called `config.php`
2. Fill in with sample string
3. Include `config.php` in `connect.php`
4. Commit to Git
5. Use `git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>` to stop tracking updates to this file.
6. Update the file with your production strings
7. If you ever need to track changes again use `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>`

Comment: We are storing it on a `connect.php` file and including it to other files, when necessary. I can add `connect.php` file to `.gitignore` but this will ignore it for commit. I mean, our connect.php file will NOT committed and pushed to GitHub. So, other collaborators can't see that file.

Comment: you could break out any sensitive strings to a new include file.  Upload a sample version of this file to Git so people know how to configure it for their server.  Afterwords you just don't commit your production version

Comment: `git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>` This is exactly what i need ! Thank you @NSjonas.

Answer (score 0):

Put a file called .gitignore inside your folder that contains the name of the file you want to ignore !

Comment: But this will ignore it for commit. I mean, our connect.php file will NOT committed and pushed to GitHub. So, other collaborators can't see that file.

Comment: I see your point. I don't know then, but I think my approach is still valid. As NSjonas said, you would commit a template for the config file and your developers would have a static version of the file. After all, it is probably never gonna change.